# "not very much" vs. "a little"

Tags: meaning, adverbs

I'm looking at a chart having quantifiers with verbs in it including *a lot* / *quite a bit* / *a little* / *very much*. I've seen these a lot but now this chart made me think more and wonder. I understand all but the last two sentences.

Does “*it snows **a little***” mean the same as, more or less as  “*it **doesn't** snow **very much***”?

I've searched and couldn't get a straight answer! There were some arguments concerning the implication of expectation, and apparently has remained unconcluded, but here has nothing to do with expectation at all anyway. Actually they were simply put in a chart, but there is no distinction based on their intensity.

Comment: Related: **1.** [Can we say “little salty”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108973/can-we-say-little-salty) **2** [“I have little money” vs. “I have a little money”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34590/i-have-little-money-vs-i-have-a-little-money) **3.** [How these words “a little” & “little” & “some” change the meaning of the sentence below?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56048/how-these-words-a-little-little-some-change-the-meaning-of-the-sentenc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be no quantitative difference between *a little* and *not very much*. It's all a matter of perspective. Most commonly (i.e., when not use sarcastically), the first tends to mean that you are encouraged by the amount and the second that you are discouraged.

> It snowed a little last night. We might be able to go skiing today.

You want to go skiing and you hope that the amount of snow will be sufficient.

> It didn't snow very much last night. I doubt we can go skiing today.

You want to go skiing and you worry that there won't be enough snow for that.

Comment: Oh I see. Then it's the matter of perspective. It kind of has something to do with being enough or not enough then. _a little_ has a positive connotation while _not very much_ a negative one. Is that so? BTW I inderstand that you take the quantity the same, right?

Comment: @Yuri: Pretty much.

Comment: I agree with Robusto. Also, if you added the word "only" to "a little" ("only a little"), then that phrase would have almost the same negative connotation as "not very much." So if it snowed "only a little," then you might also fear there is not enough snow to go skiing.